# Generate HMAC SHA256 signature Powershell

Tags: powershell, hmac, sha

For 3commas I tried to generate a HMAC SHA256 signature in Powershell with the example parameters from the documentation:

```
$secret = 'NhqPtmdSJYdKjVHjA7PZj4Mge3R5YNiP1e3UZjInClVN65XAbvqqM6A7H5fATj0j'
$message = '/public/api/ver1/accounts/new?type=binance&name=binance_account&api_key=XXXXXX&secret=YYYYYY'

$hmacsha = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA256
$hmacsha.key = [Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes($secret)
$signature = $hmacsha.ComputeHash([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes($message))
$signature = [Convert]::ToBase64String($signature)

$signature
```

It generates "MPZ4oVcjApDgBHXP/8y8kq42WdlMFFosDp0Poo9BwRo="

As [described in the documentation](https://github.com/3commas-io/3commas-official-api-docs/blob/master/rest-api.md#signed-endpoint-examples-for-post-publicapiver1accountsnew) it should generate "30f678a157230290e00475cfffccbc92ae3659d94c145a2c0e9d0fa28f41c11a"

```
[linux]$ echo -n "/public/api/ver1/accounts/new?type=binance&name=binance_account&api_key=XXXXXX&secret=YYYYYY" | openssl dgst -sha256 -hmac "NhqPtmdSJYdKjVHjA7PZj4Mge3R5YNiP1e3UZjInClVN65XAbvqqM6A7H5fATj0j"
(stdin)= 30f678a157230290e00475cfffccbc92ae3659d94c145a2c0e9d0fa28f41c11a
```

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the BitConverter class.

```
$secret = 'NhqPtmdSJYdKjVHjA7PZj4Mge3R5YNiP1e3UZjInClVN65XAbvqqM6A7H5fATj0j'
$message = '/public/api/ver1/accounts/new?type=binance&name=binance_account&api_key=XXXXXX&secret=YYYYYY'

$hmacsha = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA256
$hmacsha.key = [Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes($secret)
$signature1 = $hmacsha.ComputeHash([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes($message))
#$signature2 = [Convert]::ToBase64String($signature1)

[System.BitConverter]::ToString($signature1) -replace '-', ''
```