# How to generate an HMAC-SHA256 signature using an API key as the secret key

Tags: python, c#, powershell, api

I need to call an API in Power BI from a SaaS located here: https://apidocs.unleashedsoftware.com/AuthenticationHelp

I already have my API ID and API Key.

The endpoint I am trying to work with is /StockOnHand and it requires 4 headers, one of which requires the API Key to be encrypted with HMAC-SHA256, which is not possible in PowerBI directly.  The documentation is pretty good on the site, but I am struggling and keep getting 403 forbidden errors in Postman so I know it is an auth issue.

I don't care if I need to use Python/Powershell/C# or whatever it may be, but I need some help encoding this properly.

Yes I have looked at somewhat similar SO posts, but to no avail.

Comment: Looks like they have sample code in c#, have you tried it?

Comment: HMAC is not an encryption algorithm. It uses a hash algorithm like SHA256 to create a *Message Authentication Code* (a MAC) that can be used to verify the integrity of the message, and because it's based on a shared secret key, verify the identity of the sender. There's no encryption in there at all

Comment: What about the other question didn't work for you? Could you go into more detail? This one seems quite reasonable to solve the issue at hand: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53054659/5229138

Comment: I am not sure what to put for the 'message' as I have no parameters and the Unleashed API says that if you are just hitting an endpoint you need to use the GetSignature method.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman Yes I downloaded the .sln file and ran the web app.  It doesn't actually give me the encoded signature that I need to plug in power bi.  It just launches the app with a web UI and lets you access the API that way, but I need to use Power BI.

Comment: Update: I was able to add a breakpoint in the C# sample code and pass in my api key/API Id and capture the return value of the hmac64 variable, but I am still getting a 403 forbidden error.  Wondering if my base URL is incorrect.  "description": "(403) Forbidden.: Authentication denied - signature mismatch."